# Foxpro: How to export cursor into txt file

Tags: cursor, export, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am currently having issues exporting data from my cursor into a txt file. Unfortunately the txt file has to look a certain way. I have my cursor which I just named "Export" and have to push it into a txt file so that it looks like this.The asterisk also has to be there.

*Col1,Col2

Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10.

and repeat about 647 times. I have been searching for a good way to do this, but I feel as if my end result is too specific, which I hope isn't true. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
set textmerge on noshow
set textmerge to myfile.txt
select export
scan
    \\*<<col1>>,<<col2>><<chr(13)>>
    \\<<Col1>>,<<Col2>>,<<Col3>>,<<Col4>>,<<Col5>>,<<Col6>><<chr(13)>>
endscan
set textmerge off
set textmerge to
```

The line that stops at col6 you would obviously continue in the same way up to col10, I truncated it to fit here.